# Typescript: check key and type combination of any interface property separately as function arguments

Tags: typescript, interface

Given a variable with an interface:

```js
interface Model {
  textField?: string;
  hasMeaning: boolean;
  percentage: number;
  readonly someMap: {
    [key: string]: string;
  };
  getMeSomething(code: string): string;
}

let model: Model;
```

I'd like to check for key names and value types separately in such function:

```js
const setField = (fieldName: WritableKeysOf<Model>, fieldValue: Model[WritableKeysOf<Model>]) => {
  model[fieldName] = fieldValue;
}
```

so when I use it like that:

```js
setField('textField', 1);
setField('non-existant', true);
setField('someMap', { 'it': 'does not matter' });
```

I get errors, but these will be ok:

```js
setField('textField', undefined);
setField('percentage', 2);
setField('getMeSomething', code => code + 'suffix');
```

I wanted to achieve:

- `fieldName` should match any interface prop name but one with `readonly` ✔️
- `fieldValue` should match any possible type from the interface but one with `readonly` ✔️
- combine both so I can set a value without error ❌

I found some tricks to remove `readonly` and get types for both arguments correctly, but for some reason `model[fieldName]` is `never` now. Maybe I could use some generics to tell which interface prop exactly I want to check?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=33&ssc=53&pln=31&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsAmEA2yDeAsAFDLKQAeYAYsLpgPwBcyAzmFKAOYDcJZACzitUEOCG4sARunQ4xIPqWQAHaEnBwuEFiACuAWynQlZKGMzoQOAJ5t0BiKjgqWRZWQDaAawg2W7JwgXAC6ARzcpsgAvlHaYKIAyg4QYALcABQIWDpsEcEAlOFBvCTRJCTyYMgGOTgsGNg4SiRgNmrIAJIwAKIAjnpwOKwAPAAaADTIAJpTAIJTAEIAfMgAvPzIGSMAKssZBeurO8gQVBAgmKzIY8gMyACMyCwATIdnkJesm9t7B0fIE4fC5XGZ3R7PZBvcFzSGLFrENodADqnDAcCk8gA0n5WAB5GC7VZrZA9CgIHB6bAjdxeAAKyFAyF8NnQMEBYS6vQGQ1G%20GQngAioyQMg6Zydp5xTEpvyALTmOCWax2IUisUSqUhGViqYgCAAN2gyzKPj8bI5Uz0lwgMFAEEwywR2RA7DYqVo9HWWzt9AAcnBHCxUcB0ZiIDibPjCY1cMspr6cJgAGpDPS5WM4TwhsPY3EEkaZ5YhQ5rVa0mp1TyJzABxzakk11OUiBKcrEEgAek7yCGeCkSpIrA9dCTGQA5JQaKPMOOpg8Ckph9P6BOQFY5WdgOxxGA5%20QoOnF0OR6vx6wUs4VPv%20ePQ%20OWOPLBBruvqgY4GBIFBxzFjx3iG7XscDwLhZEwE8VzHScPk9JN92tbA7X1TB-2XODMAnNQoA0dFtH3N4l1PaD4iSFI0m4fdsmwAFqJQABqZBzz0GA7QocdFyAA)

Comment: `setField<T extends WritableKeysOf<Model>>(key: T, value: Model[T])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Ingo Bürk has suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59002905/1541563#comment104256107_59002905), you can introduce a constrained type parameter to associate the `fieldValue`'s type with the respective `fieldName`:

```
const setField = <T extends WritableKeysOf<Model>> (fieldName: T, fieldValue: Model[T]) => {
  model[fieldName] = fieldValue;
}
```